# Bash script to identify a date

Tags: bash, date

I am trying to parse my /var/log/messages.  I need a script that can verify the first 15 characters are a date.  Every now and then, it contains a line like `"---------------"` which messes everything up.

A typical /var/log/message looks like:

```
Aug 12 13:22:33 xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
```

My bash script looks to pull out the first 6 char and identify it as a date

```
if date -d "${line:0:3} ${line:4:2}" ; then
```

This works fine and identifies the date, but if the line is a bunch of -----, it identifies it as a date too.

How can I just check if the line starts with a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a strict comparison:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^[A-Z][a-z]{2}\ {1,2}[0-9]{1,2}\ [0-9]{2}(:[0-9][0-9]){2} ]]; then
    echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
fi
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the help.  Glen Jackman's might work too, but I can't copy and paste, so  had to manually type it in and it didn't work.I may have fat fingered something.

Answer (score 4):

Check that the beginning of the line looks like a date:

```
line="Aug 12 13:22:33 xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx"
if [[ $line =~ ^([[:alpha:]]{3} +[[:digit:]]{1,2} [:[:digit:]]{8}) ]]; then 
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

```
Aug 12 13:22:33
```

Comment: I'm surprised that worked without escaping or quoting the spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for line starting with `----` like this:

```
[[ "$line" != "----"* ]] && if date -d "${line:0:3} ${line:4:2}" ; then
```

Comment: too limiting. All I need is to find some other strange line that is not a date, and this fails.

Comment: In your question you only wrote about presence of `-----`

Answer (score 1):

If you've perl installed, install [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date::Manip) and your script becomes:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PERL=/usr/bin/perl
$PERL -MDate::Manip -e 'Date_init(); return 1 if parseDate($_); return 0;' $*
```